# Binding values from another UserControl (both leveraging the same ViewModel)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have 2 independent user controls (not parent child relationship) as shown below:

[image]

Problem Statement: How do I pass the aggregate values calculated (on the fly) in UserControl2 to UserControl1. Both are leveraging the same ViewModel (DataContext for both set to CommonViewModel)

More Technical Details:

- The Aggregate values are all calculated in XAML (using aggregate functions of a 3rd party control - in this case Telerik)
- I understand that I should/would have public properties on my ViewModel which will hold these values (being set from UC2 upon loading/calculation)
- The Aggregate values are not displayed in the UC2 hence cannot use the simple 2 way binding mode (to set the public property on the ViewModel)
- This is not a telerik related specific question

Specific questions:

1. How do I set a value in the ViewModel for a value which is not displayed in UC2 ?
2. Is this overall approach right - wherein I am using a public property on ViewModel as a storage mechanism to propagate values within 2 user controls. I dont have any specific requirement to store these values to a persistent store (such as DB) at any point of time.

Edit - here is the code snippet -

```
<telerik:RadGridView
        Name="ABC"
        ItemsSource="{Binding appstats}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn
                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                Header="Name"
                TextAlignment="Justify"
                IsFilterable="False">

                <!-- Telerik Count Function to get total number of Names -->
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                    <telerik:CountFunction FunctionName="AppCount" />
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                <!--End Region -->
             </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
```

Within the same usercontrol (UC2.xaml) today - I do the following:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock Text="Total number of Names:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding AggregateResults[\AppCount\].FormattedValue, ElementName=ABC}" />
</StackPanel>
```

*This second section of the code is what I want to move to UC1. As suggested below (and had tried it already) - I can hide this element here and have it set a value in VM but was trying to avoid that approach.*

Really appreciate any insight on approach and specific code snippet.

Thanks

Comment: `The Aggregate values are all calculated in XAML` - That's the problem. If you need data to be treated as `Data` and be shared / accesible throughout the application then don't put it in the UI level.

Comment: Correct - But once I get a value in XAML - cant I set it to a public property in my ViewModel (propofate value from View to ViewModel). That should be possible right? Probably using custom DP ??

Comment: I'm not familiar with Telerik so I couldn't tell, but yes you should be able to (using code behind just to send the values back to the VM)

Comment: Correct - dont want the solution to be specific to Telerik. But can you please point me to any articles where a XAML value (which is not displayed in UI) is set back to a public property in VM)

Comment: One way is to collapse the control in UI but still have two-way binding - the calculations (if not dependent upon render size) will still occur. If that is not an option - what is the control and the property (of the control) that holds the calculated value?

Comment: could you post the XAML which calculates the values .. that seems kinda strange to me ...

Comment: Just posted the code snippet

Comment: You could simply use a OneWayToSource binding in UC2 and a OneWay binding in UC1.

Comment: what about giving the textblock a name and registering it's textchanged event insidethe UC itself , there you can populate a DP or raise some command to pass to the other UC .

Comment: Eran - yes - an approach that works but frankly if I have to leverage a textblock in UC2 - then might as well just bind that value back to a public property in VM rather than using an event and then setting a DP. I would think thats extra work which could be avoided. But agree the approach would work. I am trying to avoid the textblock decalration all together in UC2 (if possible)